# C++, Protobuf can't recognize other protos as fields

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm using C++ and Protobuffer 3.19.1. I'm using this version specifically because I still occasionally use the "optional" fields.

I have the following .proto example file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message PCollect {
  string site = 1;
  string id = 2;
  int64 ts = 3;
  optional PUser user = 4;
  optional PItem item = 5;
}

message PUser {
  int64 ts = 1;
  string name = 2;
  int64 num = 3;
  optional int64 opt = 4;
}

message PItem {
  int64 ts = 1;
  string name = 2;
  double price = 3;
  double size = 4;
  optional string id = 5;
}
```

In my C++ code I have a function where I receive as input either a PUser or PData message, I want to include said message in a PCollect proto, and save that to binary. Each PCollect instance is gonna have only 1 of the 2 fields. In my function I do:

```
PCollect append(const std::string site, const std::string id, const PUser user) {
    PCollect data;
    data.set_site(site);
    data.set_id(id);
    data.set_ts(user.ts());
    data.set_user(user);
    return data;
}
```

I have another identical function with PItem instead of PUser. When I try to compile, it compiles the proto correctly, but when it compiles C++ I get this error:

```
collector.h:47:12: error: ‘class PCollect’ has no member named ‘set_user’; did you mean ‘has_user’?
```

I get the same error for the other function trying to use PItem. It's not my first time using this design pattern and including protos inside other protos, so I can't understand why I'm getting this error. I tried cleaning out and re-compiling my protos only, but I wasn't able to get it to work. I also tried putting PCollect below the other 2 structs in the .proto file but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

For cases [Embedded Message Fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#embeddedmessage)
Protobuf is not generating the setter as `set_yourfield()`, instead of is `YourField* mutable_yourfield()` and `set_allocated_yourfield(YourField*)`

With `YourField* mutable_yourfield()`, an instance will be initialized, and return a direct pointer. You can use this pointer as a setter. Example:

```
auto user_ = data.mutable_user();
user_->set_num(6);
```

With `set_allocated_yourfield(YourField*)`, you must create an instance of `YourFiled` pointer, then set it for the message.
If the pointer is not null, the message takes ownership of the allocated, so you don't need to thinking freeing memory. Example:

```
PUser* user_ = new PUser;
data.set_allocated_user(user_);
user_->set_num(0);
```

Refer to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#string) to get more information.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing a workaround on my problem for now but will try this solution eventually